# Looping through an array and copying the modified items into another array returns only repetitions of the last set of modifications

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create an array of many weeks called availabilityArray based on the model of an already existing array called weekArray that contains a set of week days. The new array is supposed to begin with the original items in weekArray and then newly modified items will be pushed in in sets after each for-loop cycle. Now the problem is that all the sets of items in the availabilityArray look similar as the previous sets get changed to the last modified set pushed in.

Please can someone tell me what I got wrong? Here is my code:

```
const weekArray = [
        this.monday,
        this.tuesday,
        this.wednesday,
        this.thursday,
        this.friday,
        this.saturday,
        this.sunday
      ];
      console.log(weekArray);

      const availabilityArray = [];
      const newArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        weekArray.forEach(item => {
          //Add 1 week to each week number
          item.weekNumber = item.weekNumber + i;
          //Add 7 days to each date
          item.date = new Date(Date.parse(item.date) + i * 7 * 8.64e7);
          newArray.push(item);
        });
        availabilityArray.push(...newArray);
      }
      console.log(availabilityArray) //It prints out a repetition of the last set of pushed in objects.
```

Comment: You're modifying the objects in the week array directly, then pushing references to those objects into the new array. When you push an object, it doesn't automatically make a copy, so any updates on those objects will be visible to anything that references them. If you want to push different variations on the objects to the new array, you need to either copy the weekday object and push the copy, or create a new object with the correct values and push that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @IceMetalPunk in the comments, you'll need to create a new object with the data you intend to push. I've attempted to reproduce the data `weekArray` contains based on the code you provided, but the values may not be exactly the same as what you have.

```
const weekArray = [
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561359600000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561446000000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561532400000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561618800000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561705200000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561791600000},
  {"weekNumber":25,"date":1561878000000}
];

console.log(weekArray);

const availabilityArray = [];
const newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  weekArray.forEach(item => {
    //Create a new item with an incremented weekNumber value
    //and a date 7 days after the given date value
    let newItem = {
      "weekNumber": item.weekNumber + i,
      "date": item.date + (i*7*8.64e7)
    };
    newArray.push(newItem);
  });
  availabilityArray.push(...newArray);
}

console.log(availabilityArray)
```